# How to communicate between microservices - Orchestration or Choreography Style

Tags: microservices

I have an application that contains several microservices.

```
For example, microservices: A,B,C,D,E,F,G
```

Form those microservices I build several processes.

```
For example,

P1: A-->B-->C-->E

P2: B-->C-->A-->G-->D

P3: A-->G

P4: A-->B-->E

...
```

The microservices communicate between them through RabbitMQ.

If I execute process P1, I don't want that any other process will be executed (probably need to save state)

In the future I may want to add more microservices, and more processes.

I'm wondering how and where to set the logic of microservices path per process.

Should each microservice call directly to the next microservice (using RabbitMQ) according to the specific process (as in the example above)?

Or, would it be better to add a "manager" microservice which will know the exact order per process, and each microservice will communicate through manager?

For example,

```
P1: Manager-->A-->Manager-->B-->Manager-->C-->Manager-->E-->Manager

P2: Manager-->B-->Manager-->C-->Manager-->A-->Manager-->G-->Manager-->D-->Manager

P3: Manager-->A-->Manager-->G-->Manager-->Manager

...
```

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you only need the set your `RabbitMQ` events correctly.

In your example, `microservice A` is responsible for starting `P1`, `P3` and `P4`, so you should have 3 different event types, e.g., `Start P1`, `Start P2` && `Start P3` and the `microservice A` should subscribe to all of them and start each process accordingly.

After `microservice A` processes an event it should create a new one, e.g., if it processed `Start P1`, then it should create an event, e.g., `P1 Step1 Completed` which will then be subscribed by `microservice B`.

This way you can discriminate easily each process. Note that I am using dummy names, in a real world scenario your event names should be concise and clear.